# How to make SMTP Server secure using Java

Tags: java, security, spring-security, smtp

I am building a banking application in Java using Spring framework that involved sending email (using SMTP server) but I heard that it's not secure. So how can I make SMTP secure in Java? Is SSL layer and/or HTTPS connection sufficient? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making SMTP secure in your java application you need to make cofiguration changes to your SMTP server so that the server will relay mails only from specific ids and ignore others.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use SMTP over SSL with Spring. Here's the sample:

XML Resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailS enderImpl">
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<property name="port" value="465" />
<property name="protocol" value="smtps" />
<property name="username" value="yourAccount@gmail.com"/>
<property name="password" value="yourPassword"/>
<property name="javaMailProperties">
<props>
<prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.debug">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" >
<property name="from" value="yourAccount@gmail.com" />
<property name="subject" value="Your Subject" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Test Class

```
package test.mail;

import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.test.AbstractDependencyInjecti onSpringContextTests;

/**
* MailTest.
* @author jalarcon
*/
public class MailTest extends AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests {

private MailSender mailSender;
private SimpleMailMessage mailMessage; 

/* (non-Javadoc)
* @see org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringConte xtTests#getConfigLocations()
*/
@Override
protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
return new String[] {"/beanDictionary/mail.xml"};
}

public void testSendMail() {
//Create a thread safe "sandbox" of the message
SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage(this.mailMessage);
msg.setTo("yourAccount@gmail.com");
msg.setText("This is a test");
try{
mailSender.send(msg);
} catch(MailException ex) {
throw new RuntimeException(ex);
} 
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------- getters/setters

/**
* @return the mailSender
*/
public MailSender getMailSender() {
return mailSender;
}

/**
* @param mailSender the mailSender to set
*/
public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

/**
* @return the mailMessage
*/
public SimpleMailMessage getMailMessage() {
return mailMessage;
}

/**
* @param mailMessage the mailMessage to set
*/
public void setMailMessage(SimpleMailMessage mailMessage) {
this.mailMessage = mailMessage;
}

}
```